# Getting counting errors with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I'm making a program that counts the logs in a database for the stats page, my query counts how many logs for each month. The problem is I have counted the logs and there is a count difference between my numbers and the numbers the database is giving me. I broke the data up so it would be easier to read. Maybe I'm doing the query wrong, but this is the best I can figure out right now. Maybe someone can maybe fix this or give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

QUERY

```
select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(log_date,"%M, %Y") AS month, count(*) as numberOfVisits
from support.support_logs
group by month
order by log_date desc;
```

OUTPUT

```
month           numberOfVisits
"March, 2015"       2
"February, 2015"    5
"January, 2015"     11
"December, 2014"    18
"November, 2014"    19
"October, 2014"     5
```

DATA

```
PHP time()  Converted to readable
1413849800  2014-10-21 00:03:20
1413849800  2014-10-21 00:03:20
1413849800  2014-10-21 00:03:20
1413936200  2014-10-22 00:03:20
1413936200  2014-10-22 00:03:20

1414973000  2014-11-03 00:03:20
1414973000  2014-11-03 00:03:20
1414973000  2014-11-03 00:03:20
1414973000  2014-11-03 00:03:20
1415750600  2014-11-12 00:03:20
1415750600  2014-11-12 00:03:20
1415837000  2014-11-13 00:03:20
1416096200  2014-11-16 00:03:20
1416096200  2014-11-16 00:03:20
1416096200  2014-11-16 00:03:20
1416096200  2014-11-16 00:03:20
1416096200  2014-11-16 00:03:20
1416096200  2014-11-16 00:03:20
1416701000  2014-11-23 00:03:20
1416701000  2014-11-23 00:03:20
1416701000  2014-11-23 00:03:20
1416701000  2014-11-23 00:03:20
1416701000  2014-11-23 00:03:20

1417392200  2014-12-01 00:03:20
1418342600  2014-12-12 00:03:20
1418342600  2014-12-12 00:03:20
1418342600  2014-12-12 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1418429000  2014-12-13 00:03:20
1419033800  2014-12-20 00:03:20
1419033800  2014-12-20 00:03:20
1419465800  2014-12-25 00:03:20
1419465800  2014-12-25 00:03:20
1419465800  2014-12-25 00:03:20
1419465800  2014-12-25 00:03:20
1419984200  2014-12-31 00:03:20

1420589000  2015-01-07 00:03:20
1420589000  2015-01-07 00:03:20
1420589000  2015-01-07 00:03:20
1420589000  2015-01-07 00:03:20
1420589000  2015-01-07 00:03:20
1421885000  2015-01-22 00:03:20
1421971400  2015-01-23 00:03:20
1421971400  2015-01-23 00:03:20
1421971400  2015-01-23 00:03:20
1422317000  2015-01-27 00:03:20
1422317000  2015-01-27 00:03:20

1423267400  2015-02-07 00:03:20
1423267400  2015-02-07 00:03:20
1423267400  2015-02-07 00:03:20
1423267400  2015-02-07 00:03:20

1425168200  2015-03-01 00:03:20
1426118600  2015-03-12 00:03:20
1426118600  2015-03-12 00:03:20
```

Comment: how much is the sum of all rows in the db?

Comment: there are 60 rows in the table, the errror is the February and March numbers they are suppose to be 4 and 3 respectively

Comment: hmmm that's strange behaviour.  add this timestamp 1422748940 to your db and see if  any new problem between january and february will appear

Comment: "March, 2015",  2
"February, 2015" 5
"January, 2015"  12
"December, 2014" 18
"November, 2014" 19
"October, 2014"  5

Comment: you see ? like I've told you your system has parsed my value as january while it is February

Comment: why is it doing that?

Comment: execute this query SELECT @@global.time_zone; tell me please what does it show ?

Comment: Comes back as: SYSTEM

Comment: You have any privilege to the system or the server ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74060/discussion-between-manvaril-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert between TIMESTAMP values and Unix timestamp values, the conversion is lossy because the mapping is not one-to-one in both directions. For details, see the description of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function. 
which means

```
1425168200  2015-03-01 00:03:20
```

the value above is an example how unix_timestamp is lossy your mysql server reads on the 1st march while it is still 28th of february on other timezone

The solution is to change timezone on either MySQL or PHP so the DateTime on both servers will be in accord